# Brakets keyboard shortcut to move focus to treeview

Tags: treeview, adobe-brackets

This should have been relatively easy to fine out , turns out its not, so actually all i really want is a shortcut with which i can toggle between the text editor and the treeview on the left.

The brackets documentation really don't mention any such shortcut [see here](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Shortcuts).

In Atom text editor for example there is a shortcut `ctrl+0` which shifts focus to the tree view , i can't seem to find such a shortcut in brackets though. I love all the features of brackets, but i just seem to be short of this one last shortcut to make my work flow awesome !!

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Comment: As a workaround, you can press `F2` to rename the current file and then cancel by pressing `Esc` and the focus will still be on the file name in the tree view.

Comment: @hirse nice , but i still would prefer a dedicated keyboard shortcut !